# Facebook event after converting from profile to page

Tags: facebook, events

We recently converted a Facebook profile to a local business page, now the old profile had one event on it that we were set up as the host for. The event is still there but we can no longer share it to our timeline and it doesn't show up in our events tab or events app, however we can still edit the event.

Also as another concern the link back to the "host profile" is linking to our old profile.php?id=xxxxxx this seems to be mapped correctly when logged in but when not logged in we get a "this content is unavailable" message, despite the fact that the new page is publicly accessible.

Any pointers or tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's a bummer. Have a lot of people clicked attending? If not many have I would just recreate the event on your biz page.